# снс (cnn) + python 3 + captcha

Tags: python-3.x, captcha, neuralbase

Здравствуйте! Мне дали задание написать свёрточную сеть для распознавания капчи, без использования готовых нейросетевых решений (т.е. саму сеть я должен написать сам). Я попытался найти примеры свёрточной сети на python, но нашёл только с использованием внешних библиотек. Подскажите, пожалуйста, учебник/ресурс/статью с похожей задачей и её решением